# How do I pass variables from the script to the files I am generating using cat?

Tags: bash, variables, echo, substitution, cat

I am not sure if I am asking the question correctly.

This is what I working with:

```
a=foo
b=bar
cat 1.txt > new1.txt
```

Contents of 1.txt:

```
$a
$b
```

When run this, my new1.txt looks like this:

```
$a
$b
```

What I want:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `envsubst`:

```
export a="foo"
export b="bar"
envsubst < 1.txt > new1.txt
```

Output to new1.txt:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed "s/\$a/$a/; s/\$b/$b/" 1.txt > new1.txt
```